# liberty 8.5.5.2 + eclipse + maven : deploy issue

Tags: eclipse, maven, websphere-liberty

According to guide -https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven#deploy,
I made pom.xml like below

---

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>1.0</version>
               <configuration>
                    <serverHome>D:\eclipses\eGovFrameDev-2.7.0-64bit_Liberty\wlp</serverHome>
                    <serverName>defaultServer</serverName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <id>deploy-app</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <appArchive>D:\eclipses\eGovFrameDev-2.7.0-64bit_Liberty\workspace\Test\target\Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</appArchive>                  
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

When I ran 'mvn -X liberty:deploy' I got exception like below

---

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins:liberty-maven-plugin:1.0:deploy (default-cli) on project Test: **CWWKM2155E: There is no application to be deployed as specified by the appArchive attribute** -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins:liberty-maven-plugin:1.0:deploy (default-cli) on project Test: CWWKM2155E: There is no application to be deployed as specified by the appArchive attribute
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: CWWKM2155E: CWWKM2155E: There is no application to be deployed as specified by the appArchive attribute
    at org.codehaus.mojo.pluginsupport.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: CWWKM2155E: CWWKM2155E: There is no application to be deployed as specified by the appArchive attribute
    at net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins.applications.DeployAppMojo.doExecute(DeployAppMojo.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.pluginsupport.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:122)

### ... 21 more

please give me expert advise how to resolve this issue and then deploy application on IBM WAS Liberty with maven

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven command line you can execute a goal (as you are doing in this case) or a lifecycle phase (for example *install*). In the pom.xml snippet you attached you have a plugin-level configuration (with *serverHome* and *serverName*) and execution-level configuration (with *appArchive*). The issue is when executing a specific goal of a plugin from the command line only the plugin-level configuration is used. That's why the plug-in does not see the *appArchive* configuration. However, if you were the execute a Maven phase such as *install*, the execution-level configuration would be used (at the right time) and the application would be deployed.

If you want the deploy goal to work from the command line just move the *appArchive* configuration to the plugin-level configuration. Also, the following might be helpful: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html